# How to get list of skills like Linkedin?

Tags: android, arrays, api, autocompletetextview

I am working on an android app, where people will share somethings like their skills but now the thing is that i want a list of skills so users can easily search and pick a skill from suggestions of an `AutoCompleteTextView` like **linkedin**.

But for autoCompleteTextView we need an array of strings to show in the autoComplete list. But i did not able to find any api for this. And i also can't make an array of strings in app in *stings.xml* because it will increase the size of the apk upto 5 to 6 MB.

[image]

I need a solution for this.

Comment: is your question about how to get a list of skills or about how to add it to the view?

Comment: Hey @UlrichStark i will add it by watching a tutorial or maybe ask it here later but for now the question is "how to get a list of skills" ?

Comment: you could find a free source on the internet or create the list for yourself... I dont think there are other options

Comment: i have already searched a lot about this but i did'nt find any way so i asked it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't know any popular API for skills listing but you can try either [this Open API](https://github.com/workforce-data-initiative/skills-api/wiki/API-Overview) or [this one](https://www.itsyourskills.com/skills-api-and-profiler/). The first one is very old and I don't think it has been updated and well-formatted(skill-names). The second one is more like a profiler, but maybe they provide API for skills too. Also, there is one site called "EMSI Skills API ", though I don't know if it really provides Skills API or not.

Comment: Wooh! @S.M You're awesome , both the APIs are seems so useful, 2nd one is paid. Hey brother i need one more favor can you please tell me how can i use the 1st github api in my android app. I already have seen a similar api for all the English words which was in python and i really don't know how to use them in kotlin.  Please suggest me any article or tutorial, you would be so greatful for me.

Comment: Yes, 2nd is paid one but they do have a free plan for the lower operation. Use Retrofit for fetching API data. It may feel like a mess at the beginning if someone never worked with API before, but you can find plenty of tutorial on it. Simply search "Kotlin and Retrofit 2 Tutorial".

Comment: Maybe this one help:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBCE_hOFnQU

Comment: Thank you so much @S.M,  you are so helpful and so kind ❣️, and i checked the tutorial and also the  EMSI it looks like what i was finding for... This is one of the best bounty answer ever i get.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add more on above answer,You can explore **EMSI Skills API** to get a master list of skills (around 30k) and all you have to do is to register and get the necessary access keys. Below is the sample Python code to fetch the skills data from EMSI SKILLS API

```
import requests
import json
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

auth_endpoint = "https://auth.emsicloud.com/connect/token" # auth endpoint

client_id = "ajhdjhaDJqwjjskfjksdjfklj" # replace 'your_client_id' with your client id from your api invite email
client_secret = "asjsajf" # replace 'your_client_secret' with your client secret from your api invite email
scope = "emsi_open" # ok to leave as is, this is the scope we will used

payload = "client_id=" + client_id + "&client_secret=" + client_secret + "&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=" + scope # set credentials and scope
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} # headers for the response
access_token = json.loads((requests.request("POST", auth_endpoint, data=payload, headers=headers)).text)['access_token'] # grabs request's text and loads as JSON, then pulls the access token from that

def extract_skills_list():
  all_skills_endpoint = "https://emsiservices.com/skills/versions/latest/skills" # List of all skills endpoint
  auth = "Authorization: Bearer " + access_token # Auth string including access token from above
  headers = {'authorization': auth} # headers
  response = requests.request("GET", all_skills_endpoint, headers=headers) # response
  response = response.json()['data'] # the data

  all_skills_df = pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(response)) # Where response is a JSON object drilled down to the level of 'data' key
  all_skills_df.to_excel('all_skills_emsi.xlsx')

extract_skills_list()
```

Comment: how can I get the EMSi API while a have a client id, secret, and scope?

Comment: just replace the vaue of client_id,secret and score in the above python code.  this is the enpoint of skills API that you need to call "https://emsiservices.com/skills/versions/latest/skills"